# How to pick a specific type of file (XML , txt) via GPM using a Business Process in Sterling Integrator

Tags: b2b, ibm-sterling

Hi i am learning basics of MFT and i want to create a business process that picks a particular type of file like xml or txt only, when i pass it

I do not know how to solve this issue

Any help would be really welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the File system adapter Extract service in B2B integrator. There is a filename filter you can use so the service will only collect files that match a specified filter within the collection folder. Examples: 
*.txt or *.xml .

```
    <process name="ExampleFileCollection"> 
<operation name="File System Adapter"> 
<participant name="ExampleCollectionFSA"/> 
<output message="FileSystemInputMessage"> 
    <assign to="." from="*"/> 
    <assign to="Action">FS_COLLECT</assign> 
    <assign to="collectZeroByteFiles">false</assign> 
    <assign to="deleteAfterCollect">false</assign> 
    <assign to="fileModTimeThreshold">60</assign> 
    <assign to="filter">*.txt</assign> 
    <assign to="initialWorkFlowId">FIND_MESSAGE_CONSUMER</assign> 
    <assign to="maxThreads">10</assign> 
    <assign to="noFilesSetSuccess">false</assign> 
</output> 
<input message="inmsg"> 
    <assign to="." from="*"/> 
</input> 
</operation> 
    </process>
```

Comment: Hey thank you , it worked and i am now learning a lot of great things in MFT